# Angular 4 Routing - Direct URL navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is my route

```
{ path: 'product/:productName/:id', component: ProductComponent }, 

{ path: 'Vitamins', component: ProductComponent }
```

I have anchor tag like below

```
 <a [routerLink]="['./product', 'Vitamins', 1]" >Vitamins</a>
```

If I click on anchor tag, I am getting name and id in params like this on NgOnit.

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params): any => {
   let id = +params['id'];
   let name = params['productName'];});}
```

Everything works great when I click on click but when I type in Url like www.website.com/Vitamins. It is not routing me anywhere. I am expecting vitamins as string and as parameter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What params would you expect for `/Vitamins`? It doesn't contain any path parameters, or any query parameters.

Comment: Did you type www.website.com/product/Vitamins/1

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know it did not contain parameters, Am expecting Vitamins as parameters. Can I get that ?

Comment: If you used the right URL, you might - according to your route specification it should be `.../product/Vitamins/1`. `Vitamins` just routes directly to the component without any parameters, **as you've specifically configured it to**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I configure to get vitamins as a parameter? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want multiple routes to the same thing? You could do e.g. `{ path: ':productName', component: ProductComponent }`, but `params['id']` still won't be set.